# Oracle 11g Encryption

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, transparent-data-encryption

Can somebody please tell me how to encrypt an existing tablespace in 11g? The wallet has been setup and the sqlnet.ora points to it.

```
SQL> select STATUS  FROM V$ENCRYPTION_WALLET;

STATUS
------------------
OPEN
```

I alter the tablespace offline ...

```
alter tablespace USERS offline normal;
```

But I can only find the 12n and above command for the next part:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE users ENCRYPTION OFFLINE ENCRYPT;
```

Many thanks in advance for the 11g command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypting an existing tablespace became possible in 12.2.

11g documentation:

[Creating an Encrypted Tablespace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e40393/asotrans.htm#ASOAG640)

> You cannot encrypt an existing tablespace.

12.1 documentation:

[About Creating Encrypted Tablespaces](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ASOAG/configuring-transparent-data-encryption.htm#GUID-5B8CCF8D-278D-411B-B8EF-F69F9364D762)

> You cannot change an existing tablespace to make it encrypted.

Comment: So in that case (11g) the tablespace is offlined and the datafiles are individually encrypted? It has to be possible as DataGuard doesn't automatically encrypt the standby in 11g so it's done manually.

Comment: @Franco Yes, it is possible, that is functionality that was backported to 11.2.0.4 and 12.1.0.2. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/asoag/encryption-conversions-tablespaces-and-databases1.html#GUID-79072DFC-4DC6-4920-9B2A-D649123D15C7 Also, for Data Guard: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/availability/tde-conversion-dg-3045460.pdf I used these steps myself as well as part of on-premise -> cloud migrations.

Comment: Excellent. Many thanks.